# Debug Visual Studio 2010 tests using nunit-console and VS-macro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, nunit-console, visual-studio-macros

I'm trying to debug tests from visual studio using nunit-console using a VS-macro, but I'm having issues when attaching the debugger / IDE to nunit-console / nunit-agent. I do have the macro working, if I just want to run the test, the issue is only when attaching the debugger.

I seem to have a deadlock issue of sorts. When I kickoff my macro, it freezes the IDE. After the attach, the test pauses at a break point (i think),but I cant see this, since the IDE is frozen. I cant stepthrough etc, since the macro is locking up the IDE, and I cant continue the test, since its halted at a breakpoint. Any ideas?

I cant use resharper / testdriven / extensions etc, no 3rd party, dont ask :(, so its the macro, something like it, or nothing.

Using Nunit 2.5.7, VS 2010, .net 4 projects.

What I have so far

```
process.Start() 'run nunit-console

If attachDebugger then
 For Each debugProcess As EnvDTE.Process In DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses

   ' no parent process ID on process type, so have to look at name for the agent.
   If debugProcess.ProcessID = process.Id Or debugProcess.Name.Contains("nunit-agent") Then
     debugProcess.Attach()
   End If

 Next
End If    

process.WaitForExit()

DTE.Debugger.DetachAll()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a guess, but I suspect that Visual Studio is running the macro on it's lonesome UI thread.

Perhaps you could try this:

In your Macro, spin up another thread and run the code you've written in that. Let the Macro exit immediately.